# How to move branch files to another branch?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have some files and directories in the master branch, and I've created another branch named 'dev'.

I would like to know the trick to move all the master content to the 'dev' branch, without committing to the dev branch and delete all master content.

Comment: why would you delete the master content?? To get a new branch with the same content as master, do a **git checkout -b `new_branch`** from the master. Then do a **git checkout master** and manually delete all the files..

Comment: ok that works, put it as an answer, I'll accept it :)

Comment: That is why you forked a `new branch`, so that you write code on your own branch. Why do you care about the master? When the code in your `new branch` gets approved and ready, then it can be merged with `master`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a new branch with the same content as master, do a **git checkout -b `new_branch`** from the master. Then do a git checkout master and manually delete all the files..

Hope this helps!!